# Azure DevOps REST API move tasks between columns in Sprints (Iteration Backlog) Board

Tags: azure, rest, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to move tasks between columns in Sprints Board (the one in Boards/Sprints NOT in Boards/Boards). When using the default Agile process tasks only have 3 states (New, Active, Closed) however there are 4 columns (New, Active, Testing, Closed) and users can easily add more. I can't find a way to move tasks via REST since Active and Testing columns share the same Active state.

I know I can create an inherited process and configure tasks to have more states so they can be one-to-one with columns, but I'm trying to find a way to move tasks that doesn't require any special configuration in DevOps.

So far I tried getting columns extension field via:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{org name}/{project name}/{team name}/_apis/work/boards/Stories?api-version=6.0
```

which game me path `/fields/WEF_972C71911C3C4154B957B669F5464FCC_Kanban.Column` and allowed me to move User Stories in Story Board (in Board/Board). Any way to make this work with Sprint Board?